# Why is R prompting me and failing on `update.packages()`?

Tags: r, ubuntu, curl, libcurl, cran

I'm new to R and I've compiled it myself on Ubuntu 14.04.3 (x64).  Note, I am up to date with the R source:

```
blong@work:~/Documents/Work/REPOS__svn/R/R-3-2-branch$ svn info |head -n 7
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/blong/Documents/Work/REPOS__svn/R/R-3-2-branch
URL: https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-3-2-branch
Relative URL: ^/branches/R-3-2-branch
Repository Root: https://svn.r-project.org/R
Repository UUID: 00db46b3-68df-0310-9c12-caf00c1e9a41
Revision: 69384
blong@work:~/Documents/Work/REPOS__svn/R/R-3-2-branch$ svn status -u
Status against revision:  69392
```

Running `configure` and `make` in R's 3.2.2 branch have completed successfully and I'm able to use a variety of packages within an R session.  However, I'd like to check that all of my libraries are up to date.  In R 3.2.2 , I'm invoking `update.packages()`.  When the function is invoked, I'm prompted to select a CRAN mirror :

[image: CRAN mirror selection dialog]

Assuming everything is fine and this is a non-issue, I select the main ("`O-Cloud [https]`") mirror from the dialog.  The dialog closes and I'm returned to my R prompt with a duplicate message saying "`unsupported URL scheme`".

Simultaneously, I receive an error in my R session upon invoking `update.packages()`:

```
> getOption("repos")
    CRAN 
"@CRAN@" 
> update.packages()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  unsupported URL scheme
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  unsupported URL scheme
>
```

Considering that perhaps this is an issue with HTTPS, I try a non-SSL mirror and similarly nothing happens (perhaps there are no updates, but I'd like a message that tells me this).  However, this time I don't receive the second "unsupported URL scheme" message after the dialog closes :

```
> update.packages()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  unsupported URL scheme
>
```

It seems that under the hood, R uses a library called RCurl to do some of it's HTTP/S interaction.  As far as I can tell, I'm using a supported version of curl / libcurl :

```
blong@work:~$ curl --version
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Any thoughts on this?  It seems similar to this [mailing list discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/update-packages-behavior-td4711966.html), but I'm not sure if this is an issue or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The appropriate site for this question among the various R mailing lists might be R-SIG-Debian: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian , since Ubuntu is a Debian fork.

Comment: @BondedDust I appreciate that (also appreciate your edit to the tags :) ).  I agree with the change to the tags, certainly.  However, I'm not sure I agree regarding where this question should be posted (e.g. what if it affects all users on Linux / Unix and not just Debian-based distributions).  I'll continue investigating and post here if I find a solution.

Comment: What happens if you do `options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.rstudio.com"))` before `update.packages()`?

Comment: Did you read the Ubuntu help pages on setting up repository keys for R packages?  It's not clear to me whether that's your problem or not.

Comment: Thanks all for the help.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32617545/320399) for details.  It seems I forgot a critical step upon configuring R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well don't I feel silly.  I don't come from a very strong C/C++ background.  So `make` isn't really in my wheelhouse apart from following guides, etc.

I was looking through this with a colleague and we discussed the steps I took to get R configured on my machine.  Effectively I did this :

```
svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-3-2-branch ~/R-3-2-branch
mkdir ~/R-3-2-branch.build
cd ~/R-3-2-branch.build
../R-3-2-branch/configure # Returns successfully
make
```

All set, right? :) I must be, because I can use `~/R-3-2-branch.build/bin/R` and everything inside that R session (except for the above error that prompted this question) seems to work just fine.  I've installed all sorts of things from CRAN, Bioconductor and GitHub; so obviously the issue must be something else.

Oh, also, I'm pretty sure all of the dependencies are properly available (in terms of platform dependencies), since I did this :

```
blong@work:~$ sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
```

Well, yeah, it was something else!  I forgot to run **`sudo make install`**!

I admit, I'm not entirely sure of which order I performed `configure`, `apt-get build-dep r-base`, and `make` in.  However, forgetting `sudo make install` seems to be the culprit.

This time around, I did the full sequence :

```
blong@work:~$ cd ~/R-3-2-branch.build
blong@work:~$ ../R-3-2-branch/configure
blong@work:~$ make
blong@work:~$ sudo make install
```

And everything appears to be running happily inside R :

```
> update.packages()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>
```

(When prompted, I've selected the `O-Cloud [https]` mirror)

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Good clear answer.  Many developers include a ReadMe w/ their source in which they provide the exact build steps (  make, make check, make install,  etc) for their code;  I bet there's some such file somewhere in the R-source-o-sphere :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks!  Yes, I'm sure you're right.  Can't believe I missed that step.  Although, since I'm not %100 certain when I invoked `apt-get build-dep r-base` it is possible that this was a PEBCAK issue (Problem Exists Between Chair And Keyboard) :)